# Vim Ctrl P take out my search highlighting. How to make the highlighting stay while in Ctrl P search mode

Tags: vim

I usually search for the route in my route file and it will be highlighted.
[image: Highlighted word in Vim]

However, when I start searching for it in Ctrl P, the highlighted word is not highlighted anymore. It really bother me to find back where exactly that word I was searching for due to the highlighting disappear in Ctrl P search mode.
[image: Highlighted Search Word Not Highlighted Anymore]

I believe there is a way to reprogram this in vimrc. I tried google, no result.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this doesn't answer your exact question ;) however, it sounds like what you're trying to do is to use the highlight to help you search.  Ctrl-p has a helpful keystroke `C-\` which brings up a prompt where you can tell it to use the `search` term as the value for ctrl-p

so.. for you.

1. `/searchforyourterm`
2. `C-p` to bring up Ctrl-p
3. `C-\` to bring up the special prompt
4. `s` to insert the searched word.

I'm not sure how to do what you're actually asking for, but perhaps the above will be what you really need :)

[link to the help doc](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt#L959-L970) or run `:h ctrl-p` and search for paste.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But not exactly what I plan to get. Basically just want the highlighted keyword to remain highlighted while in ctrl - p.